# Generate a 2d array in spiral form

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Given a number say 3 to 4 , I need to generate a 2D array in spiral form and print it.
For Example :

If given 3, the 3*3 array generated can be printed like:

```
7 8 9
6 5 4
1 2 3
```

Or, given 4, it should be 4*4 array in spiral form

```
16 15 14 13
9  10 11 12 
8  7  6  5
1  2  3  4
```

**I tried in a psudeo code to push all the numbers in a one single dimensional array.**

But I do not how to print them in such a 2D array format.

**PSEUDO _ CODE**

```
arr = new Array(val*val);// []
        let pass = 0;
        let j = 0;
        target = val*val; // 9
        while(pass < n) {
            if(pass % 2 === 0) { //pass 0 - 1 2 3 // pass 2 - 7 8 9
                for(let i = j + 1; i >= j+n; i++) {
                    arr.push(i);
                }               
                j = i;
            } else { // pass 1 - 6 5 4
                for(let i = j+n; i >= j+1; i--) {
                    arr.push(i);
                }
                j = i;
            }           
            pass++;
        }
```

Comment: `arr.map(subarr => join(" ")).join("\n")`?

Comment: it is more like a zigzag than a spiral ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using `Array.from`. First for each row generate number and then join them. The inner array could be joined on `' '`, while the outer array could be joined using `'\n'` after reversing.

```js
const generatePattern = (length) => Array.from({length}, (_, i) => {
  const subArray = Array.from({length}, (_, index) => length*i + index + 1);
  return i % 2 === 0 ? subArray.join(' ') : subArray.reverse().join(' ');
}).reverse().join('\n');

console.log(generatePattern(3));
console.log(generatePattern(4));
console.log(generatePattern(5));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the value for a certain position.

```js
const
    getZigZag = length => Array.from(
        { length },
        (_, i) => Array.from(
            { length },
            (_, j) => (length - i) % 2 
                ? (length - i - 1) * length + j + 1
                : (length - i - 1) * length + length - j
        )
    );

getZigZag(3).forEach(a => console.log(...a));
console.log()
getZigZag(4).forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```js
function a(b) {
  var c = "";
  for(var d = b * b;d > 0; d--) {
    c += d + ((d - 1) % b === 0 ? "\n" : " ");
  }
  return c;
}

console.log(a(2));
console.log(a(3));
console.log(a(4));
console.log(a(5));
```